Ubuntu 24.04. printer HP CP 1515 n does not work
Printer worked in former Ubuntu versions and still works with old HP-Laptop, but since installation of Ubuntu 24.04. the printer does not work

first check the cups service is active in your system:
systemctl status cups.service

if it isn't active or it is not installed in your system, install and active it:
sudo apt-get install cups

sudo systemctl enable cups
sudo systemctl start cups

you can use cups web interface to manage your printer:
open browser and connect to 127:0.0.1:631
then go to the printers section And see if your printer is recognized by the system or not
and enter below command to see your printer status
lpc status
Apple-Dot-Matrix:
    printer is on device 'ipp' speed -1
    queuing is enabled
    printing is enabled
    2 entries
    daemon present

you can use cupsaccept and cupsenable command if queuing or printing status of your printer in the output of top command are not enable

pls see result of lpc Status

Drucker ist am Gerät 'hp' Geschwindigkeit -1
in Warteschlange einreihen erlaubt
Drucken ist eingeschaltet
19 Einträge
Dienst verfügbar

tried everything, but printer does not work. however, produced a boot-stick with Ubuntu 24.10, and in a trial-version printer worked excellent, as in 22.04.

what is to be observed when installing 24.10? is there any danger? any special feature?

another problem is HDMI. I get the screen on tv, but nothing can be displayed. both in 24.04 and in 24.10 trial- version. Hardware is ok, everything works with an old HP windows laptop.

Migrated to 24.10, directly from 24.04, not with a boot-stick, no loss of data, printer works excellent.

HDMI problem still exists
